# Log4j appender on Wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j, jms, wildfly

I am running a Java EE project on Wildfly 10.1 Final.

I want to make a custom Log4j appender that logs to a JMS queue.
I already made a *Message Driven Bean* in my Java EE app that receives the log messages from the queue.

I created my MDB by adding this annotation:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
         @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", 
         propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
         @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", 
         propertyValue = "queue/MyQueue")
        })
```

This bean also implements *MessageListener* interface, and overrides it's *onMessage()* method where I defined the desired behaviour when the log message arrives. It looks something like this:

```
public class myBean implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {

                        if(msg instanceof TextMessage){

                            TextMessage txtMess = (TextMessage)msg;
                            String context = (String)txtMess.getText();
                            processLogData(context);
    }
}
```

I also needed to add JMS to Wildfly's *standalone.xml*, by copying all the JMS related lines from *standalone-full.xml*. I also needed to add my queue to *standalone.xml*, by adding this line to :

```
<jms-queue name="SequenceQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/MyQueue"/>
```

Now, I want to use the [JMSQueueAppender](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/trunk/contribs/Jamie%20Tsao/JMSQueueAppender.java) class provided by apache, to send the log messages to MyQueue.

I am not sure, how should I do that. Where should I put the [JMSQueueApender](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/trunk/contribs/Jamie%20Tsao/JMSQueueAppender.java) class? What values should I provide for *queueConnectionFactoryBindingName* and *queueBindingName*, and also for *initialContextFactory* and *providerURL*?

I read int this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488486/log4j-properties-doesnt-work-correctly-on-wildfly) thread that I should put `log4j.properties` file in my `EAR/META-INF`. I also read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652140/using-jmsqueueappender-with-activemq-as-jms-server) SO thread how the *log4j.properties* should look like.

Still, I am not sure which values I need to provide to the *JMSQueueApender* class, and where should I put it (how will it be initialized).

Since my project is running inside the Application Server (Java EE enviroment), and my queue is a part of that container, can I write a more simple JMSQueuApender class. Something like this:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class JMSQueueAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogSomethingBean.class);

    @Inject
    private JMSContext context;

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/jms/queue/MyQueue")
    private Queue queue;

    public void append(LoggingEvent event) {
        try {
            TextMessage msg = queueSession.createTextMessage();

            String str = (String)event.getMessage();
            msg.setText(str);
            context.createProducer().send(queue, msg);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error("An error has occured while trying to send a msg to queue", e);
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** would it be somehow possible to define one log4j.properties file for the whole Wildfly instance, so that every project that is running on it reads that configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to use this appender on Wildfly 10.1 Final.

I used the [JMSQueueApender](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/trunk/contribs/Jamie%20Tsao/JMSQueueAppender.java) class as is.

I added the log4j.properties file to the *ear/application/META-INF* (I am using Maven).

My log4j.properties looks like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, jms

## Be sure that ActiveMQ messages are not logged to 'jms' appender
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n

## Configure 'jms' appender
log4j.appender.jms=rs.netset.authority.log4j.JMSQueueAppender
log4j.appender.jms.initialContextFactory=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
log4j.appender.jms.providerUrl=tcp://localhost:61616
log4j.appender.jms.queueBindingName=java:/jms/queue/MyQueue
log4j.appender.jms.queueConnectionFactoryBindingName=ConnectionFactory
```

And, everything works